# What is the error in the following question from gfg?

Tags: python

I tried to submit [here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/mean-of-range-in-array2123/0/?category%5B%5D=Arrays&category%5B%5D=Arrays&page=1&query=category%5B%5DArrayspage1category%5B%5DArrays#) the following code:

```py
def findMean(self, arr, queries, n, q): 
    # Complete the function
    sum=0
    count=0
    li=[]
    for i in range(0,q,2):
        l=queries[i]
        r=queries[i+1]
        for j in range(l,r+1):
            sum+=arr[j]
            count+=1
        mean=math.floor(sum/count)
        li.append(mean)
    
    return li
```

But I am getting some unexpected error, for instance for `2.72727272` the output needs to be `3` whereas for `4.6666` it needs to be `4`.

Can anyone help me find what math function I need or some other way I should use to solve such errors?

Comment: In the beginning of each outer for loop, you should clear `sum` and `count` to zero.

Comment: What is in arr, queries, n, q? We cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code but it will get TLE.

```
import math
class Solution:  
    def findMean(self, arr, queries, n, q): 
        # Complete the function
        # sum=0
        # count=0
        li=[]
        for i in range(0,q,2):
            l=queries[i]
            r=queries[i+1]
            s = 0
            mean = 0
            count = r - l + 1
            for j in range(l,r+1):
                s+=arr[j]
            mean=(s//count)
            li.append(mean)
        
        return li
```

We can optimize and make it O(q + n) by calculating the prefix sum

You can undestand the concept for the prefix sum method from this link
[Mean Range Array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mean-range-array/)